# IUserPeopleCollectionRequest Request().Search() Option missing?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to search for a peroson in my Contacts with the Graph API.
I am on Microsoft.Graph (3.19.0).
The Filter Option is there, but it doesn't support fuzzy search.
It should be there as the graph explorer suggestst:

[image]

When I use this, I get the Message "IUserPeopleCollectionRequest has no definition for "Search""

**Is it not added yet?**
**Did I forget to update something?**

I can bypass this by simply doing a HTTP Request, but I would like to stick to the GraphClient, since HTTP requests are not as elegant when executet asynchronous (correct me if I'm wrong).

Some information would be appreciated or an asynchronous alternative.

Comment: Hi, if the posted answer resolves your question, please mark it as the answer by clicking the check mark. Doing so helps others find answers to their questions. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the `$search` query parameter by using QueryOptions class.

```
List<QueryOption> options = new List<QueryOption>
{
     new QueryOption("$search", "N")
};
await graphClient.Me.People
                    .Request(options)
                    .GetAsync();
```

This is exactly same as graph call

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/people?$search="n"
```

You can also use other query parameters like filter, top etc., with the help of this class.